# Java - How to create a new class that extends JFrame and has all GUI components in it while another class has all functionality?

Tags: java

Basically I know how to make a class that extends JFrame and how to implement the GUI. But I do not know how to link the functionality to another class. For example the "GUI" class extends JFrame and has all GUI elements in it. Now I have a 'Functionality' class where for example: i add cards for a card game. And now when i click a button that i created in the 'GUI' class, how do i make it create a card (create card code is in 'Functionality' class). Basically im asking how to do I link the two components to work together.

Should I put the actionListener in the 'Functionality' class? Will this solve the problem?

Comment: Add a code example so we can understand your problem better. My guess right now is that you want to seperate the GUI from the Logic . But how are you displaying the `card` on the GUI?

Comment: Yea, eveything is going to be through GUI.

Comment: So if i click the add card button, a card will be added. The adding card code is in 'Functionality' calss where as the gui for the button add card is in 'GUI'

Comment: `Should I put the actionListener in the 'Functionality' class?` Personally, I would do it like this: Create a `MyGUI` class which will have the GUI. Then create a `MyFunctionalities` class which will contain functionalities. Then create a `MyLinkClass` class which will contain code that links the two classes

Comment: I understand that part but how do you 'draw' the card? is it a graphical card? is it plain text? please provide some sort of example code of your GUI, what have you tried thus far?

Comment: @BackSlash but then where will the action listener be?

Comment: @user1232112 An `ActionListener` is something that ***links*** a GUI component to a certain logic (which will be a ***functionality***). So it will be in the `MyLinkClass`

Answer (score 0):

Provide a Controller as Singleton for the gui:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

e.g.

```
class Controller{
    private Controller _instance;

    private Controller(){

    }

    public static Controller getInstance(){
        if(_instance == null){
            _instance = new Controller();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public void addCard(Card card){

    }

    public void removeCard(Card card){

    }
}
```

you can get the controller by calling Controller.getInstance()

e.g. you can get the current controller from anywhere in your java-application you want

```
Controller.getInstance().addCard(myNewCard);
```

Another solution would be to implement strategy patterns (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) , but i would solve it with an singleton as described above.

The controller should be responsible for the logic. For gui tasks iw ould recommend to code it in your frame or as independent controller.